# ListView container is missing in the palette of Android Studio IDE. What could be the problem?

Tags: android

I want to use the ListView container in my app but the palette in Android studio IDE is missing this component. One suggested solution for a related issue was to uninstall Android studio and reinstall which seems too drastic especially for bandwidth constraint users

I have tried updating but this has not worked

Comment: You should use RecyclerView, ListView is an old component. I suppose they don't want ppl to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not missing, it moved :P[image]

it now forms part of legacy components, as you should be using a recycler view ideally

Answer (score 2):

Use RecyclerView instead of ListView.

Reasons

1) RecyclerView is an advanced ListView.

2) RecyclerView Creates views dynamically (If a screen can contain 6 items it will create only 6 views - On scrolling views will be created if needed). but in ListView all views are created once (If you have 100 items - ListView creates all at the same time).

3) So the system memory will use efficiently in RecyclerView than ListView.

Please follow these steps for implementation of RecyclerView https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score -1):

```
 <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
```

when you write this if its Shows error than you can use multitext boxs in linear layout and code its working like a listview